# How to import data from database or file to Gemfire?

Tags: gemfire

I am looking for an approach to import data from mssql to gemfire, Is it possible either from java program or Command line?

Comment: Hi! About your deleted question "Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eclipsesource/json/Json": You should use new version of minimal-json.jar (for example 0.9.5), because in version 0.91, Json class isn't exist at all. Also I recommend to undeleted question - I think it's absolutely good question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

There's no out of box functionality to import data from a `RDBMS` into `GemFire`, you'll basically need to iterate over your rows, transform them into Java Objects and insert them into the target region manually.

There is, however, a feature for [Keeping the Cache in Sync with Outside Data Sources](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html) that you can use to slowly populate the region whenever there's a cache miss for a particular key, which might be useful here.

Hope this helps. Cheers.